# Deception in Anima

Tags: anima-beyond-fantasy, social-combat, social-stats

**In *Anima: Beyond Fantasy,* what skills are used to tell lies and sense lies?**

Most games have some form of skills that can be used for such things - Bluff and Sense Motive in some versions of D&D, for instance.  Anima doesn't appear to have any Secondary Abilities that obviously fit either role.

One possibility my group has tried is using the Persuasion skill for both sides, making an opposed check.  I don't find this to be satisfying in my opinion, though, since I would consider these to be two separate skills (and they would probably use separate stats too, with the detection skill using the fairly underused Perception stat).

**What is the ideal way to handle social lies in Anima?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system lacks a stat specifically for lying to people.

In my own experience it has been used as a sub-skill of persuasion, and opposed by either your own ability to persuade someone, or with a notice check. A search if someone is actively paranoid about it, and says so. A search would also make the check considerably easier, similar to how it interacts with stealth. From there, it's up to the GM to modify it +/- based on how well the people know each other, and several of the perception modifiers could be applied, like if you can't see the persons face clearly for whatever reason.

As far as how to actually handle social lies, in my experience PC's are generally immune to the persuasion skill when used against each other. In the past, my group has had a player with problematically high persuasion skill. This caused a lot of tension and back and forth because his character was lying straight to our faces but backing it up with a massive number. In short, I would caution against overusing it. It occurs to me that this should be handled on a by campaign basis though, as a campaign centering around court intrigue for example would make this fairly important.

If you think the book is too abstract, consider making Bluff and sense motive into their own respective skills.

To quote the book:

> Naturally, it isn’t possible to list all conceivable Secondary
>   Abilities. There is always a chance that someone will think of
>   a new skill that is not on the list. If this happens, the player
>   can seek the agreement of the Game Master to create that
>   new ability. To do this, it must first be determined which
>   Characteristic governs the skill. Such an ability will have the
>   same cost as others dependent on that Field. Of course, it is
>   necessary for the Game Master to approve the rules and agree
>   to the established advantages and limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Core Exxet defines persuasion as a bonus you will get from the Master to help you decide which words you will use to convince someone, but otherwise is purely interpretation.

I think the creator of the game addressed this in some Bards Circle, basically saying the same as above. But I don't have the logs, so no way to back my memory here.

This is quite controversial, since as we all expect, high number on abilities means you are good at them, even if you as a person do not have that capacity. Including social skills.

AFAIK, my group and other groups I know that do not agree with this line of play, use Composure as a counter ability to persuasion.